# create database connection once only

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class Database {

    private String ric;
    private String volume;

    private String _url;
    private String _userId;
    private String _password;
    private String _dbLib;
    private String _dbFile;
    private Connection _conn;
    private PreparedStatement _statement;

    public Database(LSE item) {
        ric = item.get_ric();
        volume = item.get_volume();
    }

    public void writeToDb() throws SQLException{
          //setString           
    }
}
```

I have a ItemDispatcher class:

```
public class ItemDispatcher implements Runnable {

    private LSE lse;

    public ItemDispatcher(LSE lseItem) {
        this.lse= lseItem;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            new Database(lse).writeToFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`run()` method in `ItemDispatcher` runs repeatedly. I want to create database connection and `prepareStatement` in `Database` class, but doing this on Database class constuctor would create connection many times over. How can I change my design to create connection just once and not over and over again on every execution of `run()`. I am trying to not do this in any other class and just Database class

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Singleton pattern](https://blogs.oracle.com/JavaFundamentals/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) . This will allow you to have only one instace of the Database connection.
   Taking your code as an example, it would be like this :

```
public class Database {

private String ric;
private String volume;

private String _url;
private String _userId;
private String _password;
private String _dbLib;
private String _dbFile;
private Connection _conn;
private PreparedStatement _statement;
private static final Database INSTANCE;

private Database(LSE item) {
    ric = item.get_ric();
    volume = item.get_volume();
}

public static final Database getInstance(LSE item) {
   if (INSTANCE == null) {
         INSTANCE = new Database(LSE item);
    }

   return INSTANCE;
 }

public void writeToDb() throws SQLException{
      //setString           
}
}
```

If your application will be using Threads (Concurrency), I suggest you  also to prepare your singleton for those situations , [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878012/concurrent-calls-of-singleton-class-methods)

Comment: Your approach assumes that there's only one instance of ItemDispatcher.

Comment: @codenoire ,  he can still pass the ItemDispatcher, I am not assuming is just one instance of ItemDispatcher, but one instance of the connection.

Comment: You could likely not build a scalable application where two instances of a the dispatcher share a single database connection.  The second one of them needs to do something like a transaction, you're screwed.  A singleton is application-wide.  That's actually more than what the OP is asking for - he/she is asking for the run method, within the scope of an ***instance***, to use one database connection.

Comment: well , I don't see where she/he specifies the code will be deployed in a cluster or  something, what I see is someone that is starting with java, and knowing Singleton is a must, although as you comment is application-wide.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in a static block in class Database

```
static {

}
```

But this implies that Connections and Statement will be static and then shared by all instances of Database.

Just as an example from another SO post:

```
public static final Map<String, String> initials = new HashMap<String, String>();
static {
    initials.put("AEN", "Alfred E. Newman");
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the scope of ItemDispatcher, declare private variable X of type **Database**.  You might initialize it in a separate method (best) or in the constructor (might be ok).  Use the private variable X instead of creating a new instance in method **run**